# How to establish a custom xml serialization with content negotiation in spring boot 2

Tags: xml, spring-boot, serialization, jackson, content-negotiation

I'm refactoring a REST-API and want to add content negotiation to it. That works so far. 
Now I tried adding a custom xml serializer for all requests. But it is not or not properly called.

The Problem is, that I **do not have access** to the Class (`Catalog.class`) that needs to be serialized as it is imported. Therefore I need an external solution. Annotating the class does not work.

I tried using an `ObjectMapper`. But that did not help me directly. The goal is to let spring boot automatically use my xml parser whenever a response is send.

I already tried the following:

Created a XmlMapper

```java
 @Bean
    public XmlMapper getXmlMapper() {
        XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(Catalog.class, new CatalogV2Resource.Serializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        mapper.findAndRegisterModules();
        mapper.setSerializerProvider(new DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl());
        return mapper;
    }
```

tried to add it as default with the RestTemplate

```java
@Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory()));
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();

        for (HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : converters) {
            if (converter instanceof MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter) {
                MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = (MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter) converter;
                jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(xmlMapper);
            }
        }

        return restTemplate;
    }
```

This is my Serializer

```java
public static class Serializer extends StdSerializer<com.allianz.kb.Catalog> {

        @Override
        public void serialize(Catalog catalog, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
            if (jsonGenerator instanceof ToXmlGenerator) {
                jsonGenerator.writeRaw(new KbParser().toXML(catalog)); //use my own parser
            }
        }
    }
```

And a simplified version of the controller.

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/newcatalog", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<Catalog> doPostXML(@RequestParam String name) {

        //removed the stuff here for simplicity reasons
            Catalog catalog = nc.getNewCatalog();
            return ResponseEntity.ok(catalog);
    }
```

I would expect, that my parser is automatically called whenever a request with 'Accept application/xml' is received. So my XML-parser being called for a XML request and the standard JSON parser called for a JSON request.

Any help on this is highly appreciated. 
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using following class. Seems like I was missing the `@EnableWebMvc` Annotation as well as the `implements WebMvcConfigurer`

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class CustomSerializerConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

        @Bean
        public Module catalogSerializer() {
            SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
            module.addSerializer(com.allianz.kb.Catalog.class, new CustomCatalogSerializer(Catalog.class));
            return module;
        }

        @Override
        public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
            Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
            // more customization available
    //      builder.serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    //      builder.serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
    //      builder.indentOutput(true).dateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            builder.modulesToInstall(catalogSerializer());
            converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(builder.build()));
            converters.add(new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(builder.createXmlMapper(true).build()));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For automatic XML serialization and de-serialization you need to register bean of type `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter` like below -

```java
@Bean("mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter")
public MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter()
{
    return new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(new XmlMapper());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. 
Unfortunately my XML Parser is not called. Do I have to change something in my return statement? I'd think that spring boot calls the corresponding mapper on 
´return  ResponseEntity.ok(catalog);´

Comment: Yes, as long as you are making request with header `Accept: application/xml`, Spring should automatically serialize `catalog` to XML.

Comment: What are you getting in response ?

Comment: I'm getting the whole Object. Not the response I'm expecting.
actual result is
`<Catalog>
  <name/>
  <caption/>
  <kbLoader/>
  <declaredImports/>
  <declaredComponents/>
  <allComponents/>
  <importedComponents/>
</Catalog>`

Expected result should be something like:
`<Catalog>
  <name/>
  <caption/>
</Catalog>`

Comment: You may want to extend `Catalog` and exclude other properties with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "kbLoader" })`. See https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization

Comment: I actually want to avoid extending all the classes as there are much more. Instead I was looking for a way to include my parser, so that it gets injected automatically.